# Fragment - 'on navigate back' not bahave the same way as back button

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

I'm writing android app, using fragments.

There are two main ways to navigate up or back.

[picture of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViqK5.jpg)

1. The first is to use the arrow on the navigation bar (marked with the number 1 in the picture)
2. The second use the system back button (marked with the number 2)

I wrote:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
...
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_updateFragment_to_listFragment)
...    
}
```

and it works just fine, but only for system back button(2).

**How can I override action caused by click on the back arrow from navigation bar(1)?**

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got this.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "the answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

I hope this post will help someone in the future.